# How to apply sorting before post-filter in SOLR

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

I have the requirement to implement a **postfilter** plugin and it's already done but As per the official doc, it's saying **post filter is only applicable with main query and fq**. It's not allow sorting. As per my requirement, I am blocked here as I am required to do sorting before the postfilter. what is the possible way to achieve this?

reference - https://lucidworks.com/post/custom-security-filtering-solr-5/

**I wanted to apply postfilter after sorting.**

**Any help would be appreciated...**

Comment: Why do you have to do postfiltering _after_ sorting? What's the reason for that being required? Do actually want a custom similarity in addition to a postfilter?

Comment: I have to apply a few rules after sorting the data @MatsLindh

Comment: But what is the _reason_ for having to do it _after_ sorting? Are you planning to filter something based on score? What kind of rules are we talking about? Why is this required after sorting? (I understand that you want to apply a few rules after sorting the data, my question is why and if you can give an example of something that you can't achieve by filtering before sorting to understand your requirements and if possible 
suggest a solution)

Comment: @MatsLindh I have to hide a few data based on business logic after sorting, Postfilter was the best and more optimized approach but somehow it's got failed because Postfilter is only applicable before sorting.  I  implemented custom logic but that is a costly approach. I am looking for an optimized and efficient approach something similar to postfilter.